# pointers passed to functions

Tags: arduino

I am using the Arduino IDE to to write a sketch that passes data saved in progmem to a function, the function then writes the progmem data to local array. 
The code is below:

```
const uint8_t Data_3 [256] PROGMEM = {0x11, 0x39.....}
void setup() {
Serial.begin(57600);
Data(Data_3, 0x00, 256);
}

void loop() {
}

void Data(const uint8_t *data, uint8_t bank, uint16_t bytes) {
uint8_t buff1 [256];
buff1[0] = data[0];
Serial.println(buff1[0],HEX);   // <--Works fine prints the correct value
for ( uint16_t x = 0; x < bytes + 1; x++ ) {
  buff1[x] = data[x];
  Serial.println(buff1[x],HEX); // <--Just prints garbage
  }  
}
```

When I assign `buff1[0] = data[0]` and print the result the answer is correct. When I loop a print function with `buff1[x] = data[x]` I just get rubbish. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: should be bytes in the for loop not bytes +1

Comment: Why do `buff1` and `data` not have the same type? Is this an indicator of other slackness?

Comment: Why would it be byte? Yes slack, a mistake.

Comment: So this is not your actual code, or a pasting typo?

Comment: Yes this is my code, tried removing the + 1 still did not work, even with the + 1 the output would still resemble the data saved in progmem

Comment: Does the *first* iteration of the loop print "garbage"?

Comment: Yes just seems to be random

Comment: Is `uint16_t bytes` guaranteed to be 255 or less?

Comment: no thats why i used uint16_t

Comment: I asked that because the *first* iteration of the loop should print exactly the same as the `Serial.println(buff1[0],HEX);` before the loop.

Comment: Yes. I know  It dosn't though thats why I am on this forum at 22:02

Comment: @WeatherVane chances are high that `byte` and `uint8_t` are both typedefs for `unsigned char`

Comment: Is `const uint8_t Data_3 [256] PROGMEM = {0x11, 0x39.....}` your real code??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the little piece you showed ; so either the part doing the reading is messing up, or there is an error elsewhere that happens to be affecting this part

Comment: Its an extract from a 256 byte array, I just disn't want to clog the post. 'const uint8_t prgmem = {0x11, 0x39....};'

Comment: That is why i am posting here, to ask if any one knows why it does not work. The first print works fine, I used it to make sure I was not doing something wrong with the pointer. I've been trying all sorts to get it to work and nothing. Everything I've read says it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>` and `Serial.print(pgm_read_byte(data+x));` otherwise it'll try to get data from the same address but from RAM, not from Flash memory.

Or copy into the buffer by `memcpy_P(buff, data, bytes);`

Comment: Thank you, it does already have the avr/prgspace lib though. Why is the + x neccesary, is this how the array element is identified ? I will try this :) thank you agian

Comment: @user1232141234213 variable `data` contains address to the first element and if you add `x` (also called offset), it will compute correct address. It's basically the same as doing:  `&data[x]`